# Problem With Shopify CLI "To submit an issue include the stack trace"

Tags: shopify

I installed the latest versions of Ruby, Git, and Shopify CLI but  when I use the command "Shopify theme serve" I got this error and also same for the command "Shopify theme pull".

```
"X An unexpected error occurred.
To submit an issue include the stack trace.

? Send an anonymized error report to Shopify? (Navigate up with 'k' and down with 'j', press Enter to select, filter with
'f')
> 1. Yes, send
2. No, don't send"
```

[image]

And I already added `SHOPIFY_CLI_STACKTRACE=1` in the environmental variables.

I tried different solutions to solve this error but am not able to solve it.

- Shopify version: 2.15.1
- Ruby version: 3.3.7
- Git version: 2.35.1

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution to solve this error "To submit an issue include the stack trace."

1. Log out of your shopify account in the browser
2. Log out through shopify CLI (if not already logged out) `shopify logout`
3. Log in to `{shop}.myshopify.com/admin` in the browser
4. Then log in through shopify CLI `shopify login --store {shop}.myshopify.com`
5. You should be able to run `shopify theme serve` after this. If not, make sure you log out of anywhere you're logged in to shopify and try again.

This worked for me and make sure you added `SHOPIFY_CLI_STACKTRACE=1` in the environmental variable.